# How to clip image to ellipse in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206957%28v=vs.105%29.aspx there is shown a method to clip an image to ellipse, but when I copy that to my project I get an error sugesting that I cannot use ellipse geometry because expected type is "RectangleGeometry". I am building a Windows Phone 8 app.

Is there something wrong with the article or am I missing something?

My xaml code sample:

```html
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="AliceBlue">
        <Grid Margin="{StaticResource GridMargin}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Photo}">
                <Image.Clip>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100" Center="225,175"/>
                </Image.Clip>
            </Image>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="{StaticResource SmallGridMargin}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookAuthor}"></TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookTitle}"></TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"></TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: That's weird, also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip.aspx) explains that "The clipping geometry for UIElement.Clip in the Windows Runtime API must be a RectangleGeometry. You can't specify a non-rectangular geometry, as is permitted in some XAML frameworks like Microsoft Silverlight."

Comment: It's a pity then, clipping to circles has gotten kind of popular lately. :(

Comment: You can use the `Image.OpacityMask` (as described in the article) to give the same desired effect. Just make the GradientStop very close to each other (0.01 away).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.clip.aspx) says:

> The clipping geometry for UIElement.Clip in the Windows Runtime API must be a RectangleGeometry. You can't specify a non-rectangular geometry, as is permitted in some XAML frameworks like Microsoft Silverlight.

But you can achieve the same result using an Ellipse and ImageBrush element as Fill brush:

```
<Ellipse Width="100" Height="100">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Photo}"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: I tried this:

`<Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="100" >
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Photo}"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>`

But it is not working (not clipping the image).

Comment: What is resutlt then? Image is not displayed or it is displayed without being clipped? Did you remove previous element?!

Comment: Yes, I replaces Image with Ellipse, Image is shown but not clipped.

Comment: I get the image clipped by the same code, try changing width, height stretch properties and let me known if it works...or test it in a clean page...

Comment: Ok it works xD It was my image that looked the same as cropped. Please fix you answer (double source). And thanks! :)

Comment: Simple. Efficient.